# concat and append elements of array with several condition

Tags: python

Moring guys.

I have a question about how to append array elements with several condition.

assume i've array like this:

```
A=[[100,Z],[102,A],...,[9901,A]]
```

and another array like this:

```
B=[[100,-0.22,0.99],[102,-0.442,0.99],...,[9901,-1.22,4.99]]
```

The length of array A and B are different.
I want to append both the array elements with condition like this:

```
if(A[0][0]==B[0][0]):
   temp = [B[0][1],B[0][2],A[0][1]]
   array_new.append(temp)
```

I've try to append , and works , but the length of the new array is shorter than the A array.

Is something wrong with my code?

this is my code how I concat it:

```
for g in range(len(A)):
    for h in range(len(B)):
        if(B[h][0]==A[g][0]):
            temp = [B[h][1],B[h][2],A[g][1]]
            array.append(temp)
```

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be as long if not longer than A?

Comment: it must be have the same length as A. For your information ,each row of A consist of data record number and class , and  B consist of data record number , 1st data atribute and 2nd data attribute

Comment: Oh i have checked the length of A and B on my record , and , yes , it's not same at all. Not all record recorded in A , recorded too in B. But , i still not have any problem to concat A and B with  the format.

Comment: Your code have no problem. And the reason why length of the new array is shorter than the A array may because there are some value B have A donot have and some value A have but B donot have, for both scenarios, there wonot be result in new_array. And this results in you new_array's length <= any of both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This matches the elements from A and B that have the same first entry in the list.

Convert B to a dictionary with the first element as the key.

The second elements of A are converted to characters, you can't define A recursive.

```
A=[[100,'Z'],[102,'A'],[9901,'C']]

B=[[100,-0.22,0.99],[102,-0.442,0.99],[9901,-1.22,4.99]]

B_Dict = { b[0]:b  for b in B }

array_new = [ [B_Dict.get(a[0])[1],B_Dict.get(a[0])[2],a[1]] for a in A if B_Dict.get(a[0])]

print (array_new)
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED**

If you indent correctly, length of `array` must same as `A` or shorter than `A`.

Fixing indentation:

```
for g in range(len(A)):
  for h in range(len(B)):
    if(B[h][0]==A[g][0]):
      temp = [B[h][1],B[h][2],A[g][1]]
      array.append(temp)
```

Comment: *Why* must array have the same length as A?

Comment: @ScottHunter  There was a mistake in my answer. `array` will be same as `A` or shorter than `A`.